# How to fix Apache and Bitnami start error?

Tags: amazon-lightsail

I really need help with this.

I installed wordpress “By Bitnami” in Amazon AWSlightsail (Apache server).

I am trying to install SSL from SSLS.com into the domain…
I followed this doc: https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/how-to/generate-install-lets-encrypt-ssl/ 13

After research to finding a solution sadly no luck…

The problem I am facing is the server isn’t starting and here is the error:

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh status
apache not running
mysql already running
php-fpm already running
```

I tried this

```
$ systemctl status bitnami.service
● bitnami.service - LSB: bitnami init script
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/bitnami; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2022-10-02 07:48:11 UTC; 16min ago
  Process: 26919 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/bitnami start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
    Tasks: 168 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 1.6G
   CGroup: /system.slice/bitnami.service
           ├─ 3055 /opt/bitnami/gonit/bin/gonit
           ├─20092 php-fpm: master process (/opt/bitnami/php/etc/php-fpm.conf)
           ├─20096 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─20097 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─20098 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─20099 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─20100 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─20101 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─20102 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─20103 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─20104 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─20105 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─20106 php-fpm: pool www
```

Comment: I think this is off-topic for stackoverflow.com, and should have been be posted to serverfault.com, see this for an answer: https://serverfault.com/questions/232145/command-for-checking-apache-configuration 9Because you probably made a mistake in your config, but that's just guessing in my side )

Comment: @Luuk I had exactly the same error and `apachectl configtest` helped me find the line that was wrong. Thank you!

Comment: @MichaelDz - that saved me from an hour of being lost! Thanks!